# How to find the roots of a trigonometry equation with a constant?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently struggling with this, the question says :
Find the range of values of q such that the equation sin 2x = ( q/2) + (1/2) does not have any real roots.

Comment: For real $x,$  $$-1\le\sin2x\le?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sin(2x)=\frac{q}{2} +\frac{1}{2}$

Thus if  $ \frac{q}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$ then the given equation will have no real solutions .Thus, $q\in(-\infty,-3)\cup(1,\infty)$